# What is the valid address space for a user process? (OS X and Linux)

Tags: linux, macos, mmap

The `mmap` system call documentation says that the function will fail if:

> MAP_FIXED was specified and the addr
>   argument was not page aligned, or part
>   of the desired address space resides
>   out of the valid address space for a
>   user process.

I can't find documentation anywhere saying what *would* be a valid address to map. (I'm interested in doing this on OS X and linux, ideally the same address would be valid for both...).

Answer (score 7):

Linux kernel reserves part of virtual address space for itself to where userspace have (almost) no access and can't map anything. You're looking for what's called "userspace/kernelspace split".

On i386 arch default is 3G/1G one -- userspace gets lower 3 GB of virtual address space, kernel gets upper 1 GB, additionally there are 2G/2G and 1G/3G splits:

```
config PAGE_OFFSET
        hex
        default 0xB0000000 if VMSPLIT_3G_OPT
        default 0x80000000 if VMSPLIT_2G
        default 0x78000000 if VMSPLIT_2G_OPT
        default 0x40000000 if VMSPLIT_1G
        default 0xC0000000
        depends on X86_32
```

On x86_64, userspace lives in lower half of (currently) 48-bit of virtual address space:

```
/*
 * User space process size. 47bits minus one guard page.
 */
#define TASK_SIZE_MAX   ((1UL << 47) - PAGE_SIZE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I should add that I am interested only in 64-bit systems, which is why a fixed mapping is even a consideration, because it seems that there must be so much space that avoiding conflicts shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: This is a good answer for Linux. Anyone got the same information for 64-bit OSX?

Comment: Reply to my own comment: On OSX it seems to be roughly `0x1_00000000` (varies from run to run in my test case) up to `0x7fff_ffffffff`; i.e. the kernel reserves the low 4GB of virtual address space, and virtual addresses are limited to the same 48-bit range as are physical addresses on the x86-64.

Answer (score 1):

This varies based on a number of factors, many of which aren't under your control. As adobriyan mentioned, depending on the OS, you have various fixed upper limits, beyond which kernel code and data lies. Usually this upper limit is *at least* 2GB on 32-bit OSes; some OSes provide additional address space. 64-bit OSes generally provide an upper limit controlled by the number of virtual address bits supported by your CPU (usually at least 40 bits worth of address space). However there are yet other factors beyond your control:

- On recent version of linux, mmap mappings *below* the address configured in `/proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr` will be denied.
- You cannot make mappings which overlap with any existing mappings. Since the dynamic linker is free to map anywhere that does not overlap with your executable's fixed sections, this means potentially any address may be denied.
- The kernel may inject other additional mappings, such as the [system call gate](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/).
- `malloc` may perform mmaps on its own, which are placed in a somewhat arbitrary location

As such, there is no way to absolutely guarentee that `MAP_FIXED` will succeed, and so it should normally be avoided.

The only place I've seen where `MAP_FIXED` is necessary is in the wine startup code, which reserves (using `MAP_FIXED`) all addresses above 2G, in order to avoid confusing windows code which assumes no mappings will ever show up with a negative address. This is, of course, a highly specialized use of the flag.

If you're trying to do this in order to avoid having to deal with offsets in shared memory, one option would be to wrap pointers in a class to automatically handle offsets:

```
template<typename T>
class offset_pointer {
    private:
       ptrdiff_t offset;
    public:
        typedef T value_type, *ptr_type;
        typedef const T const_type, *const_ptr_type;

        offset_ptr(T *p) { set(p); }
        offset_ptr() { set(NULL); }

        void set(T *p) {
            if (p == NULL)
                offset = 1;
            else
                offset = (char *)p - (char *)this;
        }
        T *get() {
            if (offset == 1) return NULL;
            return (T*)( (char *)this + offset );
        }

        const T *get() const { return const_cast<offset_pointer>(this)->get(); }

        T &operator*() { return *get(); }
        const T &operator*() const { return *get(); }
        T *operator->() { return get(); }
        const T *operator->() const { return get(); }

        operator T*() { return get(); }
        operator const T*() const { return get(); }

        offset_pointer operator=(T *p) { set(p); return *this; }
        offset_pointer operator=(const offset_pointer &other) {
            offset = other.offset;
            return *this;
        }
};
```

Note: This is untested code, but should give you the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks: I'm interested in using it so that I can pass messages containing c++ objects between processes (I'm actually using boost::shared_memory), without having to use offset pointers.

Comment: @Autopulated, added a potential solution :)

Comment: Well, boost already has an `offset_ptr`, but I'm trying to avoid having to use it so that it isn't necessary to re-implement every type that might be used in shared memory.

Comment: The only time you can be truly sure you'll have the same mapping is if you fork with the mapping already created. Anything else has a possibility of failure with `MAP_FIXED` - so you'd better have a backup plan :)

Comment: @bdonlan: if it comes to the worst couldn't I specify my own linker map file reserving the region? (Since I'm only interested in 64-bit, I figured that the address space is so huge that collisions are pretty unlikely, too...)

Comment: Shared libraries can claim bits of your address space as well :) But I suppose you could reserve a chunk of memory, then unmap it and replace it with something else later. Just beware of mallocs in another thread performing mmaps and filling up the hole you just opened!