# How to ensure that malloc and mmap cooperate, i.e., work on non-overlapping memory regions?

Tags: macos, malloc, mmap

My main problem is that I need to enable multiple OS processes to communicate via a large shared memory heap that is mapped to identical address ranges in all processes. (To make sure that pointer values are actually meaningful.)

Now, I run into trouble that part of the program/library is using standard malloc/free and it seems to me that the underlying implementation does not respect mappings I create with mmap.
Or, another option is that I create mappings in regions that malloc already planned to use.

Unfortunately, I am not able to guarantee 100% identical malloc/free behavior in all processes before I establish the mmap-mappings.

This leads me to give the MAP_FIXED flag to mmap. The first process is using 0x0 as base address to ensure that the mapping range is at least somehow reasonable, but that does not seem to transfer to other processes. (The binary is also linked with -Wl,-no_pie.)

I tried to figure out whether I could query the system to know which pages it plans to use for malloc by reading up on [malloc_default_zone](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/malloc_default_zone.3.html), but that API does not seem to offer what I need.

Is there any way to ensure that malloc is not using particular memory pages/address ranges?

(It needs to work on OSX. Linux tips, which guide me in the right direction are appreciate, too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice this in the [`mmap` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html):

> If MAP_FIXED is specified, a successful mmap deletes any previous mapping in the allocated address range

However, `malloc` won't use map fixed, so as long as you get in before malloc, you'd be okay: you could test whether a region is free by first trying to map it without `MAP_FIXED`, and if that succeeds at the same address (which it will do if the address is free) then you can remap with `MAP_FIXED` knowing that you're not choosing a section of address space that `malloc` had already grabbed

The only guaranteed way to guarantee that the same block of logical memory will be available in two processes is to have one fork from the other.

However, if you're compiling with 64-bit pointers, then you can just pick an (unusual) region of memory, and hope for the best, since the chance of collision is tiny.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203748/what-is-the-valid-address-space-for-a-user-process-os-x-and-linux) about valid address spaces.

Comment: The most reliable way I found is unfortunately not universal:

I was able to restructure my Smalltalk VM a bit and was able to get rid of the typical `exec()` after `fork()`. This naturally preserves the mmappings. However, it comes with a bunch of other tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

OpenBSD malloc() implementation uses mmap() for memory allocation. I suggest you to see how does it work then write your own custom implementation of malloc() and tell your program and the libraries used by it to use your own implementation of malloc().

Here is OpenBSD malloc():

http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/stdlib/malloc.c?rev=1.140

RBA

Comment: I think there are much simpler solutions to this problem than rolling yet another malloc!