# Strange address of a C variable in Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, gcc

Given the following C code:

```
void *ptr;

ptr = malloc(100);

printf("Address: %p\n", ptr);
```

When compiling this code using GCC 4.9 in Ubuntu 64 bit and running it the output is similar to this:

```
Address: 0x151ab10
```

The value `0x151ab10` seems a reasonable number since my machine has 8 GB of RAM, but when compiling the same code using GCC 4.9 in Mac OS X 64 bit and running it, it gives an output similar to this:

```
Address: 0x7fb9cb43ed30
```

... which is strange because `0x7fb9cb43ed30` is well above the 8 GB of RAM. Is there some kind of bit masking that one has to do in Mac OS X so that the real address of `ptr` can be printed out?

Comment: I'd assume the address is mapped somewhere in virtual memory. Why do you need the "real" address anyway? What do you plan on doing with it?

Comment: In modern operating systems memory addresses are virtual so your address is absolutely not "strange".

Comment: Try running two of these programs simultanously (add a sleep(666) or a getchar() to prevent them from exiting too early). They could have the same address!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9208421/1679849

Comment: C pointers on those operating systems are not real addresses they are virtual addresses.  Linux and MacOS allocate virtual addresses of user space differently, so no real surprise at the numbers.  Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203748/what-is-the-valid-address-space-for-a-user-process-os-x-and-linux

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When processes run in general-purpose operating systems, the operating system constructs a “virtual” address space for each process, using assistance from hardware.

Whenever a process with a virtual address space accesses memory, the hardware translates the virtual address (in the process’ address space) to a physical address (in actual memory hardware), using special registers in the hardware and tables in system memory that describe how the translation should be done.<sup>1</sup> The operating system configures the registers and tables for each process.

Commonly, the operating system, or the loader (the software that loads programs into memory for execution) assigns various ranges of the virtual address space for various purposes. It may put the stack in one place, executable code in another, general space for allocatable memory in another, and special system data in another. These addresses may come from base locations set arbitrarily by human designers or from various calculations, or combinations of those.

So seeing a large virtual address is not unusual; it is simply a location that was assigned in an imaginary address space.

## Footnote

<sup>1</sup> There are additional complications in translating virtual addresses to physical addresses. When the processor translates an address, the result may be that the desired location is not in physical memory at all. When this happens, the processor notifies the operating system. In response, the operating system can allocate some physical memory, read the necessary data from disk, update the memory map of the process so that the virtual address points to the newly allocated physical memory, and resume execution of the process. Then your process can continue as if the data were there all along. Additionally, when the system allocated physical memory, it may have had to make some memory available by writing data that was in memory to disk, and also removing it from the memory map of some process (possibly the same one). In this way, disk space becomes auxiliary memory, and processes can execute with more memory in their virtual address spaces than there is in actual physical memory.